# Imagem no input

Tags: android

Desenvolvedores Android, preciso colocar uma imagem no começo do input:

Como posso fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente setar um código HTML detro do `EditText` usando o  método `Html.fromHtml()` usando a tag `<img>`, use também um `ImageGetter` para resolver o caminho da imagem. Além disso precisa garantir que a imagem não será apagada (talvez valha a pena usar o `hint` do `EditText`). Não pude testar, se ainda der tempo eu testo e posto uma resposta.

Comment: ok, vou testar e aguardo seu retorno

Comment: @Wakim consegui,  android:drawableLeft este é o codigo, fim do tópico

Comment: @Furlan, Poderia por o código como resposta? E então fechar a pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Para você adicionar uma imagem no canto esquerdo do edittext, pode adicionar a propriedade `android:drawableLeft` no seu XML.

Exemplo:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/editSenha"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    <!-- AQUI É ONDE DEFINO O ICONE -->
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_lock"
    android:inputType="textWebPassword"/>
```

Caso queira adicionar no lado direito, `android:drawableRight`.

Answer (score 0):

O que fiz para solucionar esta questão não envolveu 1 linha de código apenas editei uma imagem com o desenho no lado que eu queria com as resoluções necessárias para a API do android.